# How to set 'exclude_files' in Podfile rather than podspec

Tags: ios, react-native, podfile

I've created a new react-native project (0.61.5) and am trying to install [react-native-track-player](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player). The default [installation docs](https://react-native-kit.github.io/react-native-track-player/install/) are pretty sparse but after going through the issues I was able to successfully get the app running, just in a hacky way.

The solution I needed is found in [this](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player/issues/503#issuecomment-578087334) thread. Setting `s.exclude_files = ["ios/RNTrackPlayer/Vendor/AudioPlayer/Example"]` in `node_modules/react-native-track-player/react-native-track-player.podspec` works but I don't want to add it again every time my node_modules folder gets reset.

I saw in a different [thread](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player/issues/673#issuecomment-579536060) (and ended up using this as well) that setting the swift version in the Podfile to 5 in the `post_install` method will set the proper version of swift for react-native-track-player to work. I thought maybe I could move the `exclude_files` hack from node_modules podspec file to my Podfile and solve all my problems, only it seems to not work when set there:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if ['react-native-track-player'].include? target.name
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '5'
        config.build_settings['EXCLUDE_FILES'] = '../node_modules/react-native-track-player/ios/RNTrackPlayer/Vendor/AudioPlayer/Example`
      end
    end
  end
end
```

TLDR:
**Is it possible to set exclude_files in my Podfile in the post_install call?**